How to catch a redirect URL from a query URL in PHP?
When I issue an old URL :
http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=50.93554167,4.36341667&t=k&z=19

Google Maps returns (redirects to) a new URL :
https://www.google.com/maps/@50.9355417,4.3634167,169m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu&g_ep=EgoyMDI0MTIwMy4wIKXMDSoASAFQAw%3D%3D

I have a large list of old Google Maps URLs that I want to convert to the new format.
Before I can do that I need to harvest all these redirected URLs to determine the approximate relatonship between the old zoomlevels and some equivalent (rounded) altitude value in the new format.
I will use PHP to accomplish this.
The scripts suggested in php get url of redirect from source url do not work, they return a URL that is similar to the source URL.
How to do this ?

First, do you need to convert or just want to convert? I'd imagine the old URLs will continue working for a long time. Second, the first URL does redirect, but not to the second. The redirect is to adding HTTPS and change the subdomain from maps to www, both of which you can manually do. After you visit the URL in your browser, Google's JS then does something and then updates the address bar. This is not a redirect, however.

I want to convert them, but, indeed, the old ones still work. I couldn't find docs that describe the relationship between the old z parameter (zoom level) en the altitude in the new format.

To get the new URL, you would traditionally make a request and parse the response to look for the Location header. However, the curl functions give us a super-handy method so we don't need to do that ourselves. Just make the request and then call curl_getinfo():
$url = 'http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=50.93554167,4.36341667&t=k&z=19';
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($curl);
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));
curl_close($curl);

This gives us all sorts of useful data, including:
...
[http_code] => 302
[redirect_url] => https://www.google.com:443/maps?ll=50.93554167,4.36341667&t=k&z=19
...

You can also restrict the info packet to just that one value that you want. Now just wrap it in a nice function, and you can call it per URL:
function getRedirectUrl(string $url): ?string
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_exec($curl);
    $redirectUrl = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_REDIRECT_URL);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $redirectUrl ?: null;
}


This intermediary URL is what the PHP scripts mentioned in my question already gave. According to Chris Haas' comment there's an additional step in JavaScript which changes this URL into the final one. I'll compare the zoomlevels with the altitudes manually to determine the approximate relationship...
